# How to create Google app engine project which access google prediction Api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, prediction

I have work on Google prediction Api.i have create some Google Training model which work fine when i first train it->check status it-> predict it by using Google own interface for prediction api.Mean here

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/prediction/v1.6/

But now i want to train model or prediction from Google app engine project using **java** so pls anyone have some idea how to done it..The Google give example with Python but i want with java so pls help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the java API client example found at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Prediction_API

The direct link to the code is at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/prediction-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java?repo=samples

Comment: Thanks Dear i have done it by using install Application mean Java application..But if i want to run as web app Then?? Mean JSP-Servlet with Google app engine.

Comment: Hello Dear can you describe about how get list of train model using in Google app engine project.